# Fast instance per thread class - is it thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, singleton

here is a snippet from a class I am currently working at. It is intended to provide an instance ("singleton-like") per thread. A common topic here.
The typical implementation uses a locked map indexed by the thread ID and holding the data.

I tried this out, but since we make heavy use of this in our current project, it ate up an enormous amount of 3% of our whole processing power. Restructuring is currently not an option - it's legacy code pimped up for threading.

So I introduced a completely non-locked static array, which is indexed by the lower 16 bit part of the thread ID. Only if collisions occur between these (very rare), the slower and locked map access is used.

```
#pragma once
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <cstdint>
#include <mutex>


namespace Base
{

    template<typename T> class InstancePerThread
    {
    public:
#if defined( _WIN32 )
        typedef uint32_t ThreadId;
#else
#error "Not implemented"
#endif
    private:
        T* const                                    INVALID = (T*)-1;
    protected:
        std::array<T*,UINT16_MAX+1>                 m_instancesArray;
        std::map<ThreadId,T*>                       m_instancesMap;
        std::recursive_mutex                        m_lock;
    public:
        InstancePerThread() { m_instancesArray.fill(nullptr); }
        virtual ~InstancePerThread() = default;

        T& getInstancePerThread()
        {
            const ThreadId currentThreadId = getCurrentThreadId();
            T* result = m_instancesArray[(uint16_t)currentThreadId];
            assert( result && "Instance not created!" );
            if( result != INVALID )
                return *result;

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_lock);

                assert( m_instancesMap.find(currentThreadId) != m_instancesMap.end() && "Instance not created!" );
                return *m_instancesMap[currentThreadId];
            }
        }

        void createThreadedInstance( const ThreadId _threadId, const std::function<T*()>& _new = []() { return new T() }, const std::function<void(T*)>& _init = nullptr )
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_lock);


                assert( m_instancesMap.find(_threadId) == m_instancesMap.end() && "Instance already created!" );
                if( m_instancesMap.find(_threadId) == m_instancesMap.end() )
                {

                    T* t = _new();

                    // check for collision
                    T* alreadyExisting = m_instancesArray[(uint16_t)_threadId];
                    m_instancesArray[(uint16_t)_threadId] = alreadyExisting ? INVALID : t;

                    m_instancesMap[_threadId] = t;
                    if( _init )
                        _init(t);
                }

            }

        }

        void destroyThreadedInstance( const ThreadId _threadId, const std::function<void(T*)>& _destroy = nullptr, const std::function<void(T*)>& _delete = [](T* t) { delete t; }  )
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_lock);
                assert( m_instancesMap.find(_threadId) != m_instancesMap.end() && "Instance not created!" );
                if( m_instancesMap.find(_threadId) != m_instancesMap.end() )
                {
                    T* t = m_instancesMap[_threadId];
                    if( _destroy )
                        _destroy( t );
                    _delete(t);

                    T* alreadyExisting = m_instancesArray[(uint16_t)_threadId];
                    if( alreadyExisting != INVALID )
                        m_instancesArray[(uint16_t)_threadId] = nullptr;

                    m_instancesLockMap.erase( _threadId );
                    m_instancesMap.erase( _threadId );
                }
            }

        }

        static inline ThreadId getCurrentThreadId()
        {
#if defined( _WIN32 )
            return GetCurrentThreadId();
#else
#error "Not implemented"
#endif
        }


    };

}
```

Now my question is: Is this really thread safe?

As far as I can see, though m_instancesArray is read accessed from multiple threads and potentially written from another thread, there can be never a harmful race condition.

- Reading threads never access the same index
- Writing thread never changes the container size/structure (it's a static array)
- There's only a single read access: T* result = m_instancesArray[(uint16_t)currentThreadId];
- This should always return a valid pointer, which is by no means invalidated by the writing thread or INVALID, which is also ok - even if hidden race conditions occur.

Or am I missing something important here?

(Of course destroyThreadedInstance() is not thread safe when the thread to destroy its data is still running - i am aware of that. Also I am aware of the high memory cost.)

Comment: And why exactly you can't use thread-local storafe for your singleton?

Comment: Like I said: It's supporting legacy code. All of this code used singletons, which previously were not thread-aware and now shall be. Changing everything to local thread safe data would be undoubtly better, but would take too much time currently.

Comment: All you need to change is the definition of your `Instance` function...

Comment: If there are two threads whose IDs hash to the same slot in `m_instancesArray`, then you have a race between reading that slot in `getInstancePerThread`, and writing to it in `createThreadedInstance`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. The question is: Is this race harmful? As far as I can see, it isn't. - because reading from the thread will always give a valid pointer or INVALID - which then furtheron will run into the locked fallback.